# maven-dependency-plugin unpack-dependencies can't support tar containing paths over 100 characters

Tags: maven, tar, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm running into an issue with the maven-dependency-plugin (tested both versions 2.8 and 2.9) where it truncates paths over 100 characters from my tar.bz2 on extraction.

I've seen that maven assembly plugin has a `tarLongFileMode` that can be set to 'gnu', but nothing like that seems to exist for maven dependency plugin.

I've confirmed that my tar extracts fine (with both bsd and gnu tar on osx). tar itself is fine with the paths over 100 chars.

Do I simply need to accept that maven-dependency-plugin can't support tar files that contain paths with over 100 characters in length? Or am I missing something? Maybe of note is that I'm creating my tar.bz2 file manually (not using the maven-assembly-plugin) and I'm using OSX's bsd tar? I can write a script to extract my tar.bz2, but the maven-dependency-plugin looked like a ready-made solution.

Here's an example path that gets truncated:

`whyDoTheyNameThingsSoLongTest/inputFiles/somethingequallylong.validation-20140924001133_39384844diddjdf0sfhd-9384hslkjfo0001`

Here's the relevant section from my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <artifactId>big-binary-files</artifactId>
    <groupId>the-group-of-largeness</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>tar.bz2</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>unpack-big-binary-files</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/part/of/my/longpath/</outputDirectory>
            <includeArtifactIds>big-binary-files</includeArtifactIds>
            <includeGroupIds>the-group-of-largeness</includeGroupIds>
            <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same problem. To directly respond, yes, we will have to just accept it, but there are some other ways to workaround the problem.

I worked around it by using the Dependency plugin to copy the tar file to the target directory and then used the **AntRun plugin**<sup>[1](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)</sup> to use the fully featured ant functions:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <untar src="path/to/file.tar" dest="path/to/dest" />
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The Unzip Task recognizes path names that are too long for the maven dependency plugin and also has many other useful features<sup>[2](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is fixed in Maven-Dependency-Plugin version 2.10 and up:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-572